# Looking for a specific word in the context of data retention

Tags: terminology

Some time ago I read a German article that discussed the pros and cons of data rentention. One point that was made was the questionable usage of the data for things it originally wasn't meant to be collected for. For example, phone call meta data gets collected to fight terrorism. Another future government wants the already collected information for its fight against tax evasion. Hence subsequent expansion of usage.

In that specific context, the article mentioned two English words I can't remember, but they specifically described the fact I tried to describe in the second context. (:

Comment: *Repurposing*, perhaps?

Comment: I've posted an answer, but specifically related to your "expansion of usage" point is the term [mission creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_creep).

Comment: @JHCL "mission creep" was the term I was looking for. It's unfortunate that I gave a false hint. If you edit your answer I'm going to accept it :)

Comment: @MikeDooley - now done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT at the request of the OP -

The 'expansion of usage' aspect of the question is often described as [**mission creep**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_creep):

> the expansion of a project or mission beyond its original goals, often after initial successes. Mission creep is usually considered undesirable due to the dangerous path of each success breeding more ambitious attempts, only stopping when a final, often catastrophic, failure occurs. The term was originally applied exclusively to military operations, but has recently been applied to many different fields.  (-- Wikipedia)

As a relevant example of its usage in this field, see *Electronic Government: Concepts, Methodologies, Tools, and Applications* ( ed. Anttiroiko, Ari-Veikko 2007, page 1327):

> As the March 2004 Technology and Privacy Advisory Committe (TAPAC) report observes, the potential wide reuse of data suggests that concerns about mission creep can extend beyond privacy to the protection of civil rights (...)

Otherwise (*my original answer*) you could say that the data has been [**'appropriated'**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/appropriate):

> to take something for ​your own use, usually without ​permission: *He ​lost his ​job when he was ​found to have appropriated some of the company's ​money.* (-- Cambridge Dictionaries Online)

If you wanted to stress the unethical nature of the deed, then try  [**'misappropriated'**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misappropriate):

> to take (something, such as money) dishonestly for your own use : to appropriate (something) wrongly (-- Merriam-Webster)